# Django Haystack Solr - Recommended location and directory structure for Solr

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I'm using django-haystack and I am a little confused about where to put /solr, and it's schema.xml, solr.xml, and solrconfig.xml files.

I currently have /solr in the following longer path  --- /home/mydir/
solr/apache-solr3.6.0/example/

I'm thinking about moving the guts up a level (getting rid of  /apache-
solr3.6.0/) leaving ---   /home/mydir/solr/example/

It looks like the Jetty servelet is all under the example directory,
so my thought is to either change the directory name "example" to
"mysite", or save a copy of "example" as "mysite" at the same level.
In either case I end up with --- /home/mydir/solr/mysite/

I read somewhere that schema.xml, solr.xml, and solrconfig.xml should
be in the /conf directory under the "solr home" directory.  So I guess
I should create ---  /home/mydir/solr/mysite/conf and place my files
there.

I have added the following to my setting file:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    ’default’: {
        ’ENGINE’: ’haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine’,
        ’URL’: ’http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/mysite'
    },
}
```

If I set everything up as outlined above should things work?  If
someone has a clean elegant setup that works and they'd like to share
--- I'm very open to suggestions.

btw - I have worked through the solr tutorial (so solr is working),
and I have installed haystack run syncdb (so appears haystack is ready
to go also).

Answer (score 1):

actually i used it folder that contains my django project folder